# Karma: no cache on file server

Tags: karma-runner

When I do some setup on my test suite, I sometimes need to debug the produced html file.

The good thing is, there is a *debug* feature: [image: debug button]

In order to do that, I run `karma start --no-single-run`.

But on every file change I make, I need to kill the process and restart it, otherwise, cached files are served:

[image: cached]

How can I prevent the server from caching in this specific situation? Anyways, most of the time I run in `single-run` mode so caching hasn't much interest for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--auto-watch` may help:

```
karma start --no-single-run --auto-watch
```

If you change some files, karma-runner will reload (and cache) them, then it will run tests again automatically. If you refresh debug.html page after that, you will get a new version of these files without restarting karma-runner.

Comment: Seems right. But why do the files have to be cached? Couldn't karma simply setup a regular web server that loads file content on every request instead of once on load?

Comment: I guess karma relies on cache having `auto-watch` mode in mind. Karma-runner wants to restart tests as quickly as possible, that's possibly why it keeps all files in cache and reloading only changed.

Comment: Thanks @SphDev, however this did not help when running the tests from IntelliJ with run configuration for Karma.

Answer (score 1):

If you have this issue when running the tests in IntelliJ have a look at this [workaround](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-12496#comment=27-843303).

```
function runTests() {
  var serverPort = cli.getServerPort();
  var urlRoot = cli.getUrlRoot() || '/';
  if (urlRoot.charAt(urlRoot.length - 1) !== '/') {
    urlRoot = urlRoot + '/';
  }
  runWithConfig({
    port: serverPort,
    refresh: false,     // set this flag to true
    urlRoot: urlRoot
  });
}
```

It's a known, not yet fixed issue in the karma-intellij plugin.